# Parsing a Date in Daily Portfolio Report using Pythom

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have this daily portfolio report in a csv file

[Portfolio Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPRH9.png)

I want the red highlighted portfolio date to be in the first column for this portfolio report.

How should I parse this in python?

I couldn't parse it properly

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately You did not mention a few very important details:

- The number of headerrows is always the same?
- The row containing the date you are interested in always begin with "Position Date"
- the date is always displayed in the same format?

I used the assumption that the answer to these questions is always yes.
If that is the case I would do the following:

1. First, find the line contatining the date (using the csv package), by iterating through rows and looking for the line starting with "Position Date"
2. After I identified the row, extracting the date (many options here: using dateutils package or datefinder... I used the defaul regex package for that, it will always work if date format is consistent)
3. Parsing the date with datetime
4. Reading the csv again with pandas and skipping the header rows, so only the table
5. Inserting the datetime object in the first column

As there was no sample file provided I used dummy data, so you might need to change the skiprows paramater in the code below:

```
import re
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

with open('test_csv.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[0].startswith('Position Date'):
            match = re.search(r'\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}', row[0])
            date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d-%b-%Y')
        
df=pd.read_csv("test_csv.csv", skiprows=6)
df.insert(0, 'position-date', date )
```

Please accept as answer if this solution works for you.

Output dummy dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The answer to your first three questions is yes. I'll run the solution and get back